# How to access global variable from outside of canvas.onmousemove function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html5-canvas, chart.js

I have a canvas powered by chartJs to show a chart.And I defined a onmousemove function like below
to manipulate variable

```
myVariable = false;
ctx: any;
@ViewChild("mychart") mychart;

ngAfterViewInit()
{
   this.canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
      this.myVariable = true;
    };
}
```

Unfortunately it says myVairable undefined.How can I access this variable whenever onmousemove trigerred?I also tried bind(this) like below but didnt work.

```
 this.canvas.onmousemove = (function(e) {
                console.log(this.myVariable);
        }).bind(this)
```

Stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-zzqumr

Comment: If you use an arrow function instead of function(e) I believe that will fix it.  Functions have their own this context, but arrow functions bind automatically and don’t have their own this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('A', this.myVariable)
  this.canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    console.log('onMouseMove', this.myVariable)
  }
}
```

If I understand your example correctly, you get an output of

```
A myValue
onMouseMove undefined
```

but you would like to have `onMouseMove myValue` as well.

You can simply store a reference to `this` while it's still available, and use it in your `onmousemove()` handler later

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const self = this
  console.log('A', self.myVariable)
  this.canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    console.log('onMouseMove', self.myVariable)
  }
}
```

which should output

```
A myValue
onMouseMove myValue
```

Answer (score 0):

A `function` has its own `this` context, so calling `this` inside of the function body accesses the function rather than the component.  An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) does not establish a `this` scope, so you can access the component as `this` from inside of an arrow function.

```
this.canvas.onmousemove = (e) => {
  this.myVariable = true;
  console.log(this.myVariable);
};
```